# Запрет на редактирование если запись не null(Блокировки)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Есть приложение в котором есть DataGrid в котором есть заявки. За этим приложением работают несколько юзеров. И если они в один и тот же момент хотят взять в работу одну и ту же заявку, чтоб первому он дал эту заявку, а второму написал что эту заявку уже забрали. Причем кол-во пользователей свыше 100... Как можно это грамотно реализовать в SQL.

```
DECLARE @UserIdAimCheck int
SET @UserIdAimCheck = (SELECT TOP 1 UserIdAim FROM History WHERE HistoryId=@historyId)
IF @UserIdAimCheck is null
BEGIN
    UPDATE History SET UserIdAim=@userId
        WHERE History.HistoryId=@historyId
    SELECT 'Заявка успешно взята вами в работу';
END
    ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Данная заявка уже в работе, обновите таблицу!';
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если для не-взятой заявки соотв. поле (UserIdAim?) содержит NULL (или ноль), то

```
UPDATE History 
SET UserIdAim=@userId
WHERE History.HistoryId=@historyId
AND UserIdAim IS NULL /* или =0 */
```

и затем тупо контроль либо количества обновлённых записей (не ноль - получилось, ноль - кто-то успел раньше), либо SELECT по @historyId и @userId и проверка, что возвращается ненулевое количество записей.

В обоих случаях, получив ноль, сообщаем, что заявку слямзили буквально из-под носа. А обновить в таком случае можно и автоматически...